# Password hashing at client browser

Tags: security, hash, passwords

What's the best way to hash the user password at the client browser, before sending it to the web server, so that only the hash goes out, not the plain-text password?

**EDIT**: assuming HTTP is used (not HTTPS)

Comment: I hope you're planning to either send the hash over a secure channel, or this is part of a challenge/response mechanism. Otherwise, this is no more secure than sending the password itself in plain text...

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe, this method may actually be a slight improvement for the user. Even if there isn't a secure channel available (only SSL would work, no JS alternative would be bulletproof) then it would at least make the hash unique to the site. To make the hash unique, of course, *it has to be salted*.

Comment: Granted that it would make the hash unique to the site -- useful if the user uses the same password on multiple sites; doesn't prevent replay against the same site.
And, surely if the hash is salted, then either the salt has to go from the client to the server -- no more secure than before; or the other way, in which case it _is_ challenge/response.

Comment: The unique password was exactly what I was referring to, but to clarify regarding the salt; it's just to make it very hard for someone listening in on the connection to brute-force the original password (think DB storage). The authentication of the particular site the user is visiting would already be broken at this point, but that may be OK depending on the site, while exposing personal information, like the password the users chooses, is not.

Comment: By the way, since the OP seems to have no SSL available, I don't think challenge/response is feasible, since it depends on a shared secret; that is, authenticated+encrypted communication must have already taken place (e.g. SSL at signup-time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use javascript to calculate the hash. See [this](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-sha1.html) for an example on how to calculate SHA-1 hashes in JS.

Beware that if you make yourself dependant on Javascript, your system will fail as soon as someone has JS disabled. You should use HTTPS if this is a concern to you, which has its own setbacks (e.g. certificates cost money if you want them to be immediately accepted by browsers.)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this [jQuery encryption plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/1575). Out of curiosity, what's wrong with using SSL/HTTPS and encrypting at the server side?

Answer (score 1):

Not all people have JavaScript enabled in their browsers and even the idea of sending hashes on a plain-text channel I think is not secure enough.

I would recommend you to consider a [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) secured connection.

Comment: Nowadays (2018) almost all users have javascript enabled.

Answer (score 1):

This site has quite comprehensive hashing/crypto stuff: [JavaScript Encryption Library](http://farfarfar.com/scripts/encrypt/)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript side encryption like the jQuery Encryption library stops Eavesdroppers. However, MITM (Man-in-the-Middle) can still occur. SSL/TLS is the ultimate choice that is highly recommended to take unless you are on shared hosting (no dedicated IPs) or your site is receiving so much traffic that you can't simply encrypt all connections (JS, CSS, HTML, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Why would you bother doing this? Effectively, the password hash has become the password and a a man-in-the-middle who intercepts the hash can use it to authenticate and perform any action as the user. On the other hand, if you don't believe in the man-in-the-middle, why not just send the password itself?

Comment: Challenge-Response protects against Eavesdropping -where you can't alter any data, but just listen to it. Since tokens are one-time only, the eavesdroppers will always be late and gain no use of the token.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I suppose it would stop an eavesdropping-only attacker from discovering the password. But in that case, I'd just just use HTTP Digest authentication rather than rolling my own.

Answer (score 1):

Why do we hash passwords? So that if the hashes are obtained they're difficult to use.

What happens in this model if the hashes in the system are exposed? The attacker simply sends them to the server and authenticates as the user.

This is why password hashing always happens on the server, not the client!